# Kendo DatePicker Format validation and error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker, kendo-ui

I was create a page has Datepicker with dd/MM/yyyy format with culture ar-SA but when I try to set the date it's always returns invalid date
here is the datepicker

```
@Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.ValidStartDate).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "ValidStartDate_" + Model.ItemCode }).Culture("ar-SA").Format("dd/MM/yyyy").ParseFormats(new string[] {"dd/MM/yyyy"})
```

another problem is the validation message it's always return the default message instead the custom message I set in the view model

```
[Date( ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidStartDate_InvalidDate")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ValidStartDateH { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does the validation fail on the server or the client?

Comment: the validation fails in the client

Comment: Cool, have you tried different browsers? Are you using Kendo's Validator or JQuery Unobtrusive? maybe even something else?

Comment: I've tried IE and chrome with same result, and I user kendo validator

Answer (score 2):

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Pick a date from Kendo Date Picker")]
public DateTime mydate{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m=>m.mydate)
              .Name("MyDate")
              .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
              .ParseFormats(new string[] {"dd/MM/yyyy"})
```

Add script document.ready function

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        kendo.culture("en-GB");

        $.validator.methods['date'] = function (value, element) {
            var check = false;
            var re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
            if (re.test(value)) {

                var adata = value.split('/');
                var dd = parseInt(adata[0], 10);

                var mm = parseInt(adata[1], 10);
                var yyyy = parseInt(adata[2], 10);
                var xdata = new Date(yyyy, (mm - 1), dd);

                if ((xdata.getFullYear() == yyyy) && (xdata.getMonth() == (mm - 1)) && 
                    (xdata.getDate() == dd)) {

                    check = true;
                }
                else {
                    alert(value);
                    check = false;
                }

            } else
                check = false;
            return this.optional(element) || check;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) tour to get to know how this site works and what it is for. Learn formatting your answer, as it would increase readability.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the date format incorrect message by set the culture in the load script

```
kendo.culture("ar-SA");
```

but still I has the second problem which is the custom text message still not returns from the data annotation message

Answer (score 0):

Remove  [Date( ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidStartDate_InvalidDate")]
 and use this regular expression.

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(0[13578]|1[02])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)/(0[13456789]|1[012])/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])/02/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29/02/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Object), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidStartDate_InvalidDate")

public DateTime? releavingDate { get; set; }